# Configurable form to XML or JSON?

Tags: windows, xml, json, forms

I currently have a software that can display forms to edit configuration files. These forms are defined by a file that is read by the software to generate the form. The user uses the form (i.e user interface) to modify its configuration file is a very guided way, and then saves, which generates the configuration file.

I am wondering if there exists an equivalent software able to do something similar with XML or JSON. I have tested softwares like XML Notepad, but the problem is that such software doesn't provide a form which prevents the user from doing mistakes, they are just text editors that can display errors.

Comment: Should it run or Windows, Mac or Linux? Can it cost something?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, yes it must run on windows. It can cost something, but preferably not. I just found out about National Instruments Configuration Editor Framework that might be close to what i'm looking for.